# Update each jsonb value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, jsonb

I am working with a jsonb field in my user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, HashSerializer
  store_accessor :preferences, :optin, :privacy
end
```

One user preferences:

```
{
  "optin" => {
    "app" => true,
    "actions" => true,
    "other" => true,
  "privacy" => {
    "email" => 3,
    "profile" => 1,
    "intetests" => 1
  }
}
```

How can I manage to create forms with `simple_form` to edit the preferences?

Example:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: :update_optin do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :app, as: :boolean, label: 'App' %>
  <%= form.input :actions, as: :boolean, label: 'Actions' %>
  <%= form.input :other, as: :boolean, label: 'Other' %>
  <%= form.button :submit, 'Save' %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @user, url: :update_privacy do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :email, as: :boolean, label: 'Email' %>
  <%= form.input :profile, as: :boolean, label: 'Profile' %>
  <%= form.input :interests, as: :boolean, label: 'Interests' %>
  <%= form.button :submit, 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

It would be way much better if you can we can do this in just one form.

I've been looking all over the web without any clue.

Comment: you should be able to do it with a `simple_fields_for :preferences` block inside your `simple_form_for` block.

Comment: I am trying to make it that way, but is not showing the correct values on the form. Any ideas how to accomplish this?